# Два socket в одном потоке

Tags: c++, qt

Пишу сервер на qt. Вопрос такой, могу ли я по очереди проинициализировать два socket и использовать их вместе. Дело в том что пишу под кривую реализацию клиента, который создает два соединения, где одно принимает данные, а другое отправляет.

Comment: конечно можете.

Comment: попробую, надеюсь получится, просто не совсем понятно, как работают потоки ввода вывода в самом соккете

Comment: делаете сокеты не блокирующими (см. O_NONBLOCK) и скармливаете их функции select() (или более навороченному варианту poll/epoll) когда хотите ожидать данных на любом из них (не зная на каком именно). И так можно спосокно держать сотни коннектов в одном потоке